# OS X native share menu in Firefox

Tags: macos, sharing, firefox

I’d want to know if it is possible (by extensions, hack, context menu...) to have the mac native share menu in firefox?

[image: OS X share menu]

Thanks

More about share menu extension:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac

https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [sharethis](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sharethis/) add-on?

Comment: Hi, thank you but this extension do not have native mac share items

Answer (score 1):

So far as I'm aware, there are two ways to bring up macOS' native share sheet:

1. While the relevant tab is active, in the Menu Bar navigate to **File** > **Share**.
2. Right-click on the tab and mouse over the **Share** item in the context menu.

Unfortunately, as of version 106.0.1, the share sheet is not present in the context menu that appears when right-clicking on the page content.

Comment: Thank you, best answer to this question!